# Convert list to nested tuple Haskell

Tags: list, haskell, types, tuples

Short and sweet, my issue is that I am parsing a list of numbers ([Integer]), and I want to transform that list into nested tuples, so for example the list [1,2,3,4] would be (1,(2,(3,4))) this seems to me to be doable with a fold operation. I think the problem I am having is that the type is not determined before hand, making the tuple nest potentially infinite.

EDIT BASED ON COMMENTS

Thanks for the good replies, the root problem is for an assignment, so that is why details of the greater issue is sparse, but in an effort to not leave you wondering I can expand a bit, although I am not looking for answers to the expansion. My problem boils down to an issue with a right recursive and right associative part of a context free grammar, where I have something like

A -> n A

so I could get an expression like so 'n n n n A' which parses to 'n(n(n(n A)))' (A does have other terminals). I can parse it to '[n,n,n,n] A', which is why I wanted the conversion (I know there is a better way, I am just struggling to find it).

Comment: You can't do this because the type depends on the data (full on dependent types).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, that was kinda the realization I was getting at, but was hoping I had overseen something.

Comment: You could define your own custom type `data T = Empty | Nonempty (Integer, T)` to represent the arbitrary nesting of tuples, but in doing that we are only giving another name to the standard list type, so there's nothing to gain. Why do you think you need tuples for your data?

Comment: Another possible encoding: `data NTup t = Here t | There (NTup (Integer,t))`. Then you can use `NTup ()` for a nested tuple of any size. By the time you recurse down to `Here`, `t` will be a nested tuple of the appropriate size (try `show`ing it to see).  This is called a non-regular type, and I can't really see a point to doing it in this instance, but it's a good technique to know.

Answer (score 5):

As Thomas M. DuBuisson commented, this is just not really doable in a good way, since the list length is only known at runtime, but tuples of different depth have different types, and types must be known at compile time.

(Technically speaking, Haskell is actually able to act as a full dynamically typed language, by using the [`Data.Dynamic`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-Dynamic.html#t:Dynamic) type, but this really impractical to use.)

There is however another way to have a sensible-ish list-to-tuples conversion: if you *do* know at compile time what would be the correct depth, and a list of mismatching length should simply be an invalid input. In this case, you can use something like

```
{-# LANGUAGE FunctionalDependencies, FlexibleInstances #-}

class NestedTup e t where
  toNestedTup :: [e] -> Maybe t

instance NestedTup e e where
  toNestedTup [e] = Just e
  toNestedTup _ = Nothing
instance NestedTup h t => NestedTup h (h,t) where
  toNestedTup (h:t) = (h,)<$>toNestedTup t
  toNestedTup [] = Nothing
```

```
*Main> toNestedTup [1,2,3,4 :: Int] :: Maybe (Int,(Int,(Int,Int)))
Just (1,(2,(3,4)))
*Main> toNestedTup [1,2,3,4,5 :: Int] :: Maybe (Int,(Int,(Int,Int)))
Nothing
```

Comment: how did you add type constraints in instance definition, and how does it work? Also ghci complained about turning on `TupleSections`

Comment: @Yogendra you can do it just like that.  `instance <constraints> => ClassName params`.  It works by *first* selecting the instance as if there were no constraints, committing to that choice, and then trying to solve the constraints.  (Thinking of it as an "if then", while tempting, seduces you into thinking you can do things you can't)